# How to allow only same domain requests for specific directories with .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, restriction

I have some directories (let's say engine/) that should be accessed only by specific php codes sitting in public directories, so no external access needed at all.

How to restrict every access beside requests from the same domain (where the code deployed at without hardcoding a domain name)?

Can a .htaccess guru help me out here?

---

It turned out that beside referer based access I have to **deny direct access** as well somehow.

Comment: btw. I'd consider to put it simply outside of your document root.

Comment: Moreover I'm thinking of mark every 'engine' directories with a '!' in the directory name, so if you could create a mask that applies only to directories whose name contains '!', that would be truly awesome.

Comment: I have not full access the production server, I can deploy files only to a given folder... ...so I need this workaround. By the way, it gives the engine a bit more flexibility.

Comment: @bwoebi Is there such a solution at all?

Comment: something with `deny from all`. and for the directory search the apache manual for the `<Directory>` xml tag

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example from [Using mod_rewrite to control access](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html)

```
SetEnvIf Referer example\.com localreferer
<FilesMatch \.(jpg|png|gif)$>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=localreferer
</FilesMatch>
```

#### UPDATE:

To protect directories with a single .htaccess file at root directory, something like this should work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mydomain\.com [NC]
# Add/Remove directories in next line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(dir1|dir2|dir3) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you just show me how to modify FilesMatch to mask some given directory names?

Comment: By the way, is there a ".htaccess for dummies"-like tutorial somewhere out there? I really want to use it, but just haven't find a proper starting point yet.

Comment: @Geri Modified my answer. Forgot the most important part: To allow access from local domain.

Comment: Thanks there! You saved me huge bulk of time, and made my data secured... Supposing it is working code :D

Comment: When I click a link to a restricted resource, the stuff works well (throws a 403), but when I hit enter for the same link in the browser, it loads the file partially (external files, like some css, js files do not loading but the root html gets created/responded). How to get over this?